# Do I need to have my own website for publishing android paid apps?

Tags: android

actually I'm planning to publish a paid app, but when i'm signing up for the merchant account it is requesting for website url. The thing is I don't have any website, so how can i publish my app...

Thanks!

Comment: Leave it blank, you do not need a website.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about payment processors and marketing, not programming.

Comment: if i leave it blank, i'm getting an error which reads as   Business website must start with "http://"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put any website, they're not gonna check if it's wrong or not!

YOu can also put your Facebook page, e.g. `https://www.facebook.com/WHATEVER`

Comment: thanks Stefano Munarini. I appreciate your help.